# Replace vector and hash table with Boost.Bimap

Tags: c++, data-structures, boost, unordered-map, bimap

I'm looking to replace a `vector<string>` and a `boost::unordered_map<string, size_t>` mapping string to indices in the former with a `boost::bimap`.

What instantiation of `bimap` should I use? So far, I've come up with

```
typedef bimap<
    unordered_set_of<size_t>,
    vector_of<string>
> StringMap;
```

but I'm not sure if I've reversed the collection types now. Also, I wonder if I should change the [collection of relations type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/the_collection_of_relations_type.html). Would a `vector_of_relation` be my best choice, or a `set_of_relation`, or just go with the default?

Comment: Add some more information about the way in which you plan to use the data so we can determine the constraints for accomplishing what you need.

Comment: I wanted a bijection between `size_t` and `string` objects with O(1) access time for both and minimal or modest memory requirements.

Comment: @rep_movsd: yes, they are. I eventually solved the problem by using Boost.MultiIndex, which I found easier to understand. (It turned out I needed a third view of the data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217885/get-numeric-index-from-boost-multi-index-iterator.) An answer is still welcome, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a bimap between size_t and std::string where you have ~constant (up to the cost of hashing and any potential clashes) you need to use unordered_set_of:

```c++
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_set_of.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  typedef boost::bimap< boost::bimaps::unordered_set_of<size_t>, boost::bimaps::unordered_set_of<std::string> > StringMap;
  StringMap map;
  map.insert(StringMap::value_type(1,std::string("Cheese")));
  map.insert(StringMap::value_type(2,std::string("Cheese2")));

  typedef StringMap::left_map::const_iterator const_iter_type;
  const const_iter_type end = map.left.end();

  for ( const_iter_type iter = map.left.begin(); iter != end; iter++ ) {
    std::cout << iter->first << " " << map.left.at(iter->first) << "\n";
  }

}
```

returns:

```
1 Cheese
2 Cheese2
```

The unordered_set is a boost version of set which uses hash tables instead of trees to store the elements, see [Boost Unordered docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/unordered.html).

Looking at the comments from one of the bimap examples at [Bimap example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/controlling_collection_types.html#boost_bimap.the_tutorial.controlling_collection_types.examples), we have:

> The left map view works like a std::unordered_map< std::string, long >,
>   given the name of the country we can use it to search for the population in constant time

Comment: But would this give me O(1) access time for the `size_t` side and "hashed O(1)" from the other side?

Comment: Nope it wouldn't have. Although hopefully this is corrected with my recent edit. I doubt either access (size_t or std::string) get O(1) in the worst case in this way, but they should get O(1) average case complexity.

Comment: Ok, accepted. I would recommend MultiIndex to any potential users of Bimap, though.